# Can I turn a Object.property into a String like "Object.property"?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I want to create a function to turn the keys from an object that i am accessing to a string, something like:

```
const test = {
  propertyOne: {
   propertyTwo: 0
  },
  propertyThree: {
   propertyFour: 0
  }
}


function ObjectKeysToString(objectReceived) {
  ...
  return stringfiedObjectReceived
}


Input: 

test.propertyOne.propertyTwo
ObjectKeysToString(test.propertyOne.propertyTwo)



Output: "test.propertyOne.propertyTwo"
```

Is this possible?

I've searched for this and looked for every Object method but didnt succeeded on any of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is `propertyOne.propertyTwo`. Variable names can't be accessed in runtime

```js
const test = {
  propertyOne: {
    propertyTwo: 0
  }
}


function ObjectKeysToString(objectReceived) {
  const path = []
  let current = objectReceived
  do {
    const key = Object.keys(current)[0]
    path.push(key)
    current = current[key]
  } while (typeof current === 'object' && current !== null)

  return path.join('.')
}

console.log(ObjectKeysToString(test))
```